# AD password Expiry Date of a domain user

Tags: powershell

I am using the below command to get the user info from other domain and I am getting that data successfully. how do I add filter to get the password expiry date of the user to the below query?

Get-ADuser "username" -server "abc.com"

Comment: You will find `Get-ADUser -Identity «username» -Properties * | Select-Object -Property * | Get-Member` to yield educational output.

Comment: Jeff, thanks. the query is giving me the Password expired and False,. but what I need is the specific date of password expiry and the user is another domain.

Answer (score 3):

It's not super straightforward. You have to calculate it:

```
Get-ADUser 'username' -server 'abc.com' -Properties msds-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select Name, @{n='PasswordExpires'; e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'msds-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')}}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a `PasswordLastSet` attribute:

```
#Number of days a before password expires in the domain
$PasswordLife = 30
#Get User with PasswordLastSet attribute   
$user = Get-Aduser -Identity "Some User" -Properties PaswordLastSet
#Calculate the expiry date
$ExpireDate = $User.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($PasswordLife)
```

the PasswordLastSet attribute is a datetime object so we can use the add method to calculate the expiry date.

The only problem is you need to know how long passwords are set to last for in your domain.